# Linux Command within Command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, quotes

My use case is to run a command on multiple servers remotely. I have trust set up between hosts.

So i have one command like this:
COMMAND 1:

```
for i in 11 12 13 14 15 16; do echo host-name-dev-$i; ssh -q host-name-dev-$i "nohup bash -c 'Place Ur command Here' > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null &"; done
```

And another as:
COMMAND 2:

```
rm -rf /floderPath
```

When i combine(COMMAND 1 + COMMAND 2) these two it works fine and subsequent folder is deleted from all hosts.

```
for i in 11 12 13 14 15 16; do echo host-name-dev-$i; ssh -q host-name-dev-$i "nohup bash -c 'rm -rf /floderPath' > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null &";done
```

Now i have another command. If i run this command on all the hosts individually, it works fine and kill all the java processes.
COMMAND 3:

```
for i in `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep java | awk '{print $2}'`; do kill -9 $i; echo "Process id $i is killed"; done
```

But now when i combine COMMAND 1 and COMMAND 3 it doesn't work at all. What i am trying to do here is KILLING all JAVA process on all the hosts.

```
for i in 11 12 13 14 15 16; do echo host-name-dev-$i; ssh -q host-name-dev-$i "nohup bash -c 'for j in `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep java | awk '{print $2}'`; do kill -9 $j; echo "Process id $j is killed"; done' > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null &";done
```

I can guess that there might be improper use of quotes, but i have tried various combinations and it didn't work for me.
I don't have much experience in scripting so pardon for obvious errors.

Comment: Personally, once shell scripts get even a little bit complicated, I scrap them and rewrite in Python.  It's hard to get the quotes exactly right in shell scripts and hard to debug them to figure the problems out.  If you don't like Python, maybe use Ruby or Perl or just do the whole thing in AWK.

Comment: `kill -9` should be the *last* resort only, not the first. As far as I can tell this question is about bash on most any OS so IMO Linux should be removed from the title and the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following quoting *should* work...

```
for i in 11 12 13 14 15 16; do
  echo host-name-dev-$i
  ssh -q host-name-dev-$i "nohup bash -c \"for j in \\\`ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep java | awk '{print \\\$2}'\\\`; do kill -9 \\\$j; echo \\\"Process id \\\$j is killed\\\"; done\" > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null &"
done
```

**Update**: Please do not kill yourself over the amount of escape characters.

Comment: I got the following error for this:


}`; do kill -9 ; echo "Process id  is killed"; done: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
}`; do kill -9 ; echo "Process id  is killed"; done: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @Ajay: Oops, should have checked my answer twice... Anyhow, now it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy.. Worked like charm.. :)

Answer (score 0):

bash or any other shell can't take a good proccess in remote Interaction action.

use expect language to do what you want. http://expect.sourceforge.net/

We use expect in more than 1000 hosts, It works fine, try  :)

Comment: Thanks for the response Chair.. I can understand that there are more robust languages, but point here is this command works fine for most of the scenarios. So it would be helpful if we can get this one to work.